# Forge Viewer. Retrieving from Revit

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

I set upp my App to retrieve properties information from Revit, meaning it currently retrieves Constraints, Identity Data, Phasing, etc.. But I want it to retrieve documents, links, images as well.

I created this Parameter to test:

- Type Parameter: Image
- Group Parameter under: Graphics

Then I added this parameter to an object and uploaded a .png. When I check the result inside the App, only the "Name" of the parameter under "Graphics" appears. No content. Only blank. Is it supposed to be like this or is there anything I could do to make the file upload work?

Comment: if you are trying to get PNG images (bytes) on a property, that's not supported... the propertyDb will only have text/numbers/ids on it.

Comment: Okay thanks, do you think it will be supported in the future or are there no current plans for this? Anyway, I found a workaround: https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/05/adding-custom-meta-properties-to-the-viewer-property-panel.html

Comment: that workaround is not getting the data from the RVT, but overriding the Viewer property to show a value coming from another source (e.g. your database), glad it's working for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle that at the moment would be to write your custom Revit addin that can connect to Forge and upload your model. When doing so, using the Revit API, you could parse the model properties and store the embedded pictures and documents to your own cloud database/storage.

When loading the model in the viewer, you would load a custom extension that does something alike the [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/05/adding-custom-meta-properties-to-the-viewer-property-panel.html) you are referring to, connecting to your own database and showing the embedded content.

More elaborated demos of MetaProperties are available [here](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=5904729b0007f5ead5b1196d) and [here](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=59780eec17d671029c53420e) with full source code [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.MetaProperties).

Hope that helps

[image]